# Removing the first one (whenever it stays) negative number from array using c#

Tags: c#, arrays

Found lots of different solutions so far but none of them implement my task to remove *the first one negative* number in sequence and leave others (there are multiple negative numbers in array).

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Sorry, it's unclear what you are asking. What is "not first-met"? If you could provide sample data and expected result, that would be helpful.

Comment: If this is an array don't you just need to scan through to find the one you need to remove than then move any further elements back one spot? If this was a list or enumerable there are other ways e.g. a yield-return function or .Where with a lambda that has a closure variable flag to indicate that it had already removed a negative number, etc.

Comment: @BrankoDimitrijevic , edited it. Apologize for my poor English

Comment: What is the type of your *sequence*? Elements cannot be removed from **arrays**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many possibilities:

**Linq**

```
  int[] array = new int[] { 1, 2, -3, 4, 5, -6, 0 };

  ... 

  int removed = 1;

  array = array
    .Where(item => item >= 0 || removed++ > 1)
    .ToArray();
```

**for**

```
  int shift = 0;

  for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; ++i) 
    if (array[i] < 0 && shift == 0)
      shift = 1;
    else if (i + shift < array.Length)
      array[i] = array[i + shift];

  if (shift > 0)
    Array.Resize(ref array, array.Length - shift);
```

**foreach**

```
  List<int> list = new List<int>(array.Length);

  bool found = false;

  foreach (int item in array)
    if (item >= 0 || found)
      list.Add(item);
    else 
      found = true;

  array = list.ToArray();
```

Answer (score -1):

If I understood correctly, this should work.

```
bool negFound = false;
for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++) 
{
    if ((!negFound) && (array[i] < 0))
    {
        array[i] = null;
        negFound = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: one might assume an array of int therefore setting it to null is not going to work.  The OP doesn't make it clear what they mean by "remove" so its not worth answering until they have.  They possibly mean they have a list and want to remove the entry whereby shifting all the subsequent entries up by one